# Date ticks for lineplusbar nvd3

Tags: date, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to get the exact date in lineplusbar chart using nvd3 and I got the code from http://nvd3.com/ghpages/linePlusBar.html . I'm getting the correct date for line but for bar it showing me a default date of 01/01/07. Can anyone help to get the correct date as i get it for line.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You just need to filter the right elements. In the line plus bar or cumulative line examples they filter like this:

```
chart
      .x(function(d,i) { return i })
```

All you need to do is remove this filter and you will have the right dates for your chart.

Best regards!